# UWP non-rect object collider detector

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to know if two generic objects intersect.
I tried to create two Rect of the same size of objects and using the Intersect method it works, However, this method is not accurate on objects like an Ellipse.

Is there a method that tells me if two non-rect shaped objects intersect?

```
GeneralTransform t1 = this.object1.TransformToVisual(this);
GeneralTransform t2 = this.object2.TransformToVisual(this);

Rect r1 = t1.TransformBounds(new Rect() { X = 0, Y = 0, Width = this.object1.ActualWidth, Height = this.object1.ActualHeight });
Rect r2 = t2.TransformBounds(new Rect() { X = 0, Y = 0, Width = this.object2.ActualWidth, Height = this.object2.ActualHeight });

bool result = r1.IntersectsWith(r2);
```

Comment: Using XAML to detect is not easy. Have you tried to use [win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/APIReference.htm) relevant APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HitTestCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.hittestcore?view=netframework-4.7.2).  See the documentation for the method, you need the overload that accepts `GeometryHitTestParameters`.

Edit: You get the geometry of the second object, and call 'HitTestCore' with it.

Comment: HitTestCore is not available on UWP